# Encrypting Windows Storage Space

Tags: encryption, windows-8

I use Storage Spaces for a RAID 5 in Windows 8.1. I use Truecrypt for the drive my OS is on. I use my RAID to store things like my desktop and other things that need to be available on boot. Is there any software I can use to encrypt the RAID? I cannot use Bitlocker.

EDIT: Bitlocker is not available in my OS because I do not have Pro.

Comment: You're already using truecrypt, so why not keep using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked into it a little more and figured out that there is no easy way to do this and I may loose my data if I try to encrypt the RAID. One clever solution is to make a giant encrypted file container with TrueCrypt and put it on the However I will not be doing this because I do not want a 6TB file container.

Answer (score 0):

Jetico's BestCrypt can do this.  Costly, though.  May be easier to upgrade to a BitLocker version of Win8.

Also, CryptBox may do this - I'm not sure.

How did you determine that TrueCrypt was unsuitable for 'whole drive encryption' of a drive space RAID?

Pat